# How to count the number of same immediate preceding siblings in xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm using xslt version 2, I'm trying to transform an xml to a fo output, and I'm stuck on a specific problematic.

Here is what looks like my input:

```
    <a1/>
    <a1/>
    <b/>
    <c/>
    <d/>
    <a2/>
    <b/>
    <c/>
    <a1/>
    <a1/>
    <a1/>
    <a1/>
    <b/>
    <c/>
    <d/>
```

This data, functionally speaking, contains a list of 'sets' defined by a1|a2,b?,c?,d?.

My problem is that I don't see how I can count the number of a1 tags for a specific 'set'.

Indeed, I have written my xsl and I get an output like that:

```
<fo:table>
    <fo:row>
        <fo:cell>b: </fo:cell>
        <fo:cell>b value</fo:cell>
    </fo:row>
    <fo:row>
        <fo:cell>a1: </fo:cell>
        <fo:cell>number of a1 ???</fo:cell> <-- what I am trying to retrieve
    </fo:row>
    <fo:row>
        ...
    </fo:row>
    ...
</fo:table>
```

I have done an apply-template on a1+|a2 tags, and I do nothing if a1 tag has a following sibling that equals to a1.
I think there must be a way to count the tags with preceding sibling (but then how to insure to count only the corresponding one?)

Any hints would be appreciated!

Edit: 
On the above example of input, the first count should be 2:

```
    <a1/>
    <a1/>
    <b/>
    <c/>
    <d/>
```

then it should be 4, and not 6:

```
    <a1/>
    <a1/>
    <a1/>
    <a1/>
    <b/>
    <c/>
    <d/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question is not really clear.
What should *"the corresponding one*" be? 
Counting all `a1` before the current one would be:

```
 count(preceding-sibling::a1)
```

if needed you may add predicates like:

```
 count(preceding-sibling::a1[/corresponding one/])
```

To count only the presiding sibling a1 which are in a sequence of a1 nodes try this:
Find the first node which is not an a1.

```
<xsl:variable name="firstnota1" select="preceding-sibling::*[not (self::a1)][1]" />
```

The wonted result than, is count all nodes before the current a1 minus the count of nodes before the first not a1 + this node it self.

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*) 
       -  count($firstnota1/preceding-sibling::* | $firstnota1)"/>
```

Or without variable:

```
<xsl:value-of 
      select="count(preceding-sibling::*)
             -  count( preceding-sibling::*[not (self::a1)][1]
                      /preceding-sibling::*
                      | preceding-sibling::*[not (self::a1)][1] )"/>
```

Comment: the problem is I have a1-a1-b-c-d-a1-a1-a1-b-c-d... first time it is 2, second time 3. I will edit my post

Comment: Sure it only counts the  preceding-siblings. If you like to have the count including self add `+1`: `select="count(..) - count(..) +1"

Comment: Ok that's it, my mistake was I did not understand the  | $firstnota1, so i ignored it. Instead I had to remove it and then to add 1. So it handles both cases : with or without different previous sibling.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `for-each-group group-adjacent="boolean(self::a1)">` e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::a1)">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
        <xsl:value-of select="'Count is: ', count(current-group())"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- process other elements here -->
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If the input is

```
<root>
    <a1/>
    <a1/>
    <b/>
    <c/>
    <d/>
    <a2/>
    <b/>
    <c/>
    <a1/>
    <a1/>
    <a1/>
    <a1/>
    <b/>
    <c/>
    <d/>
</root>
```

then Saxon 9 outputs `Count is:  2Count is:  4` so it outputs the numbers you want (badly formatted, admittedly). If you don't get any output then perhaps the elements you have posted have a different parent element than the one I have chosen (i.e. `root`). Or you use namespaces and the `self::a1` needs to be adapted.

Comment: I really don't get how to make it work with that, it seems i never have "current-grouping-key()"

Comment: Ok +1 my mistake I was trying to use the foreach-group in the element, not parent. But I'm displaying 421 - 421 - 421 instead of 4 - 2 - 1... It seems that the test test="current-grouping-key()" is always valid ?

Comment: No just forget it. It is a difference in conception: I build a fo table from a1, using for-each-group I should build it from parent. thanks for explanations.

Comment: Well... maybe do not forget it :) Do you think there is a way to retrieve values from groups of (a1+,b?,c?,d?) Using for-each-group seems to be really cleaner than my solution

Comment: I am sure there is a way e.g. `<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="a1">...</xsl:for-each-group>` but it might be better you ask a new question where you present small but complete and representative samples of the XML input and the corresponding FO output. Then I am sure we can find a way using `for-each-group`.

Answer (score 1):

Try following xpath

```
count(preceding-sibling::a1)-count(preceding-sibling::b[1]/preceding-sibling::a1)
```

It means: count of preceding a1 at all minus count of a1 preceding previous b

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll try it when I have the opporunity to do so.

Comment: b, c and d are optionnal (xsd says so), I will try to find if it is really optionnal or if my data will always contain one particular (if not, is there a way to find the max of count(preceding-sibling::b[1]/preceding-sibling::a1) / same with c / same with d ?)

Comment: You could store the name of actual element into variable `<xsl:variable name="nodeName" select="name()" />` and then use it in second count `<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::a1)-count(preceding-sibling::node()[name()=$nodeName][1]/preceding-sibling::a1)" />`